# how do I grep only the user created profiles among all users in linux ?

Tags: linux, grep, quota

From the below output , I just want celesial and neetish user 
I can't figure how to do it though .

```
celestial@celestial:~$ sudo  repquota  /
*** Report for user quotas on device /dev/disk/by-uuid/e312e0f3-68d6-44f1-aecb-731bd4932bf3
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                        Block limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
root      -- 3777196       0       0         203861     0     0      
man       --    3088       0       0            368     0     0      
lp        --       0       0       0              1     0     0      
libuuid   --      24       0       0              2     0     0      
syslog    --     852       0       0             10     0     0      
avahi-autoipd --       4       0       0              1     0     0      
speech-dispatcher --       4       0       0              1     0     0      
lightdm   --     224       0       0             41     0     0      
colord    --      20       0       0              4     0     0      
celestial --   98880       0       0            956     0     0      
neetish   -+    1452    2000    3000            150    20    30  3days
```

Comment: Are your users in a group, or using a UID sequence that differs from system accounts?  Or otherwise do you have a way of identifying a user account vs a system one?

Comment: Nope the users are not in a group , orwise it was a simple solution

Comment: @Paul I don't a way to identify the system user :/

Comment: Do users only have home directories maybe?

Comment: @Paul I think as :/ maybe ? but then I have to invlove like bash script here  and maybe it is not other platforms like other os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gets the repquota results for anyone with a directory in /home:

```
 repquota -t / | head -5; for i in `ls -1 /home/` ; do repquota -t / | grep $i ; done
```

The first command just runs repquota to get the heading columns, then the for loop does requota a bunch of times grepping each directory name from /home.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I get Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                        Block limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
repquota: Cannot open quotafile //aquota.user: Permission denied
repquota: Quota file not found or has wrong format.
repquota: Not all specified mountpoints are using quota.
repquota: Cannot open quotafile //aquota.user: Permission denied
repquota: Quota file not found or has wrong format.
repquota: Not all specified mountpoints are using quota.

Comment: I gave sudo also :/

Comment: You need sudo before both repquota commands

Comment: and do you have a solution for other OS ? like a genric OS ?

Comment: There isn't a generic os. What do you mean?

Comment: is /home directory there in every linux distro ?

Comment: Linux can be set in any way the administrator pleases.  /home is common, but not always present.  What you don't have is a clear definition of what a user is in this scenario, so it would be difficult to come up with anything that would work every single time.